# Why div not stacked immediately after previous div ? (not margin/padding issue)

Tags: css

I have positioned `<div id="title">` 50px above its original position, height of the div being 70px. I cant understand why `<div id="page1">` is not beginning right after the title div, but only beginning after its original height, 70px.
How can I correct it?

```css
* {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
#title {
 position: relative;
 top: -50px;
 width: 100%;
 height: 70px;
 background-color: blue;
}
#page1 {
    background-color: lightgreen;
 text-align: center;
 position: relative;
 z-index: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 500px;
}
#page1 img {
 position: absolute;
 top: 200px;
 left: 50px;
 width: 200px;
}
#page1 h1 {
 padding-top: 100px;
}
#page2 {
 background-color: red;
 position: relative;
 z-index: 1;
 width: 100%;
 height:800px;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
     <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "style.css">
 </head>
 <body>
     <div id = "title"></div>
     <div id = "page1"><h1>Hello !!!</h1><img src = "https://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2015/10/01/21/39/background-image-967820_960_720.jpg"></div>
     <div id = "page2"><div>
  <script src = "script.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Because that's the we way relative positioning works. - http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/IuLfJ The page remembers where the element was and allocates that space as though the element was still there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using position relative and the top attributes is the problem here.

By stating top: -50px the div is being visually moved from its original position however the div is still retaining its original position in the document flow

You could use margin-top -50px instead of just top. this moves the entire div and retains the spacing betweens divs.

See the docs below for the "top" property explanation.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/top

TL:DR

> For relatively positioned elements (those with position: relative)
>   the value specified will move the element below or above its position in the 
>   normal flow if it wasn't positioned.

Comment: does it affect the height of the element, i mean if visually a 50px height div is moved 10px down, relative to its original position, will it show height to be 60px ? @MatthewTilley

Comment: @DhruvChadha - it only moves the target element 10px down. It has no effect on the dimensions of the element, only the position.

Answer (score 2):

It is caused by top: -50px and position relative;

You could achieve it adding margin-top: -50px to #title div and removing top: -50px from it.

```
#title {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: -50px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 70px;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The unexpected behavior you are facing is caused by the use of `position:relative`.

To better understand the how relative works, I would suggest reading the following article:

https://css-tricks.com/absolute-relative-fixed-positioining-how-do-they-differ/

In your specific case, you could use `position:absolute` instead of relative. You can achieve in this way your result but in a simple way.

```css
#title {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0x;
  width: 100%;
  height: 70px;
  background-color: blue;
}

#page1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 70px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

#page2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 500px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 800px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="title">Title</div>
<div id="page1">
Page1
  <div>
    <div id="page2">
    Page2
      <div>
```

If you want to stick using position:relative you can fix your code adding this code.

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/yn8337hy/2/

```
#title {
  margin-top: -50px;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 70px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```